# How to handle a SOAP/XML request without a http header in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap

I need to create a solution for a SOAP service-host where the requesting client does send a http-header with his request (Wireshark shows that the client opens a TCP/IP connection and sends plain XML data like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns=...
...
</Envelope>
```

To my understanding, there should be a httpheader before the XML-Header. As the company is unable/unwilling to fix this issue, I need to find a workaround to parse the data (already got a dirty solution for it) and respond "correctly" that the client knows the request was processed.
For now I'm using the ServiceHost class in C# .Net 3.5

Is there a better solution then to manually try to assemble a response package?

*edit*
When I send a request to a web-service it looks like the following (extracted from wireshark)

```
POST /WS_DC/WS_DC.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.5485)
VsDebuggerCausalityData: ....
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "*removed*"
Host: 192.168.77.125:8080
Content-Length: 400
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://...
...
</soap:Envelope>
```

The other client only sends a soap request to my servicehost without any http header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns=...
...
</Envelope>
```

Also, I think i mixed up html and http. Changed it in the post.

Comment: What HTTP header are you talking about? SOAP information is passed as SOAP headers in the envelope.

Comment: When I do a soap request it looks like:     POST /WS_DC/WS_DC.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.5485)...

Comment: This is still quite unclear. Can you show us the difference by providing two sample codes: one HTML and one XML?

Comment: Updated the post with two examples.

Comment: What if you had two services - one normal SOAP service for internal use and another, outward facing service that receives the requests, sends them to the other service as a properly formatted SOAP requests, and then relays back the response?

Comment: @JRishe, I've done that before.  The more complicated option would be a custom transport (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmetzgar/2012/10/16/an-updated-custom-wcf-transport-channel-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem writing my own minimalistic SOAP client.

TCPListener on 8080,
Parse the XML,
Construct my own HTTP Header + XML Response
Send it back over the TCPClient.